# Draw in jPanel inside a jDialog

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have `jDialog`, it is in `BorderLayout`, in `"south"`, `"north"` and `"center"` I have `jPanel` with elements (with nothing in the "center"'s jPanel.
"center" jPanel is called Map.

I'm thing things like :

**In the main**

```
  Graphics t = Map.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(t);
```

**Not in the main.**

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
 super.paintComponents(g);
 g.drawLine(0, 0, 50, 150);
}
```

I cannot draw anything. What is the mistake I have done?

Comment: where did you place your paintComponent()?

Comment: First of all in the newDlg constructor is placed the first part of the code.
Then after it is placed paintComponent().

Comment: Painting doesn't work this way, you should never call `paintComponent` (or any paint method) directly. You should change some shared state, call `repaint` and wait for the paint system to repaint your component

Comment: You need to stop making guesses about how these things work and start researching how the API works and figure away to work with it.  Start by having a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how painting works

Comment: BTW - don't add the tag of your IDE unless the problem is ***with*** the IDE. (99.99% of the time, it isn't. It's the Java code that is the problem, and would be problematic in any IDE.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     JPanel Map = new JPanel() {
             public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

                Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(10, 10, 40, 40);
                g2.setColor(Color.blue);
                g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
                g2.draw(line);
             }
        };
        getContentPane().add(Map, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        Map.add(new JLabel(pseudo));
  pack();
```

in the dlg constructor.
    thanks for you nohelp it worked